# Rails 2.3.8 : how can I select records based on the highest value of a field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am rephrasing a question asked few days back .[click this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222421/with-activerecord-how-can-i-select-records-based-on-the-highest-value-of-a-field/4222914#4222914) to see the previous question

I have answered this question.But it is not correct.

Records in the table

[image]

```
Revision.find(:all,:select => "id,name,max(revision) as revision", :conditions => ["saved=1"],:group => 'name')
```

which would result

[image]

Actually the result should have been id 3,6,8.

what modification in query will lead this result?

Answer (score 1):

This is a query type to which SQL isn't well-suited. The problem, in a nutshell, is that what you effectively want is a group operation, and then a sort within each group, and then to take the top record from each sub-group. This turns out to be surprisingly difficult problem, because SQL does grouping before sorting. Generally, grouping is for aggregate data, rather than selecting specific records.

There are a number of SQL-specific ways to solve this, but none of them fit Rails very well. Instead, I'd structure your data like so:

1. Have a recipe_revisions model, which includes a full recipe record
2. Have a recipes model, which is basically just id/name/latest revision.
3. To get the current copy of a recipe, you'll select the recipe you want from recipes, then join to recipe_revisions on name/max revision, where those columns are indexed on both tables.

This isn't an *easy* solution, it'll work well.

Answer (score 0):

Split your query into two. In the first find the max revision for each name. In the second query find the full row which matches name and revision.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE max_revisions (name varchar, revision integer);
INSERT INTO max_revisions SELECT name, max(revision) FROM revisions
       WHERE saved = 1 GROUP BY name;
SELECT r.* FROM revisions r INNER JOIN max_revisions m
       ON m.name = r.name AND m.revision = r.revision;
```

Now your problem may be, how to express this in Rails.

You may use Revision.connection.execute and then Revision.find_by_sql (both wrapped in a single method, for example: Revision.find_by_max_revisions).

Otherwise, if your database does not support temporary tables, or you just don't want them, you may read the max_revisions into memory, and then use it to build the query:

```
class Revision
  def self.find_by_max_revisions
    max_revs = connection.select_values(
      sanitize_sql(
        ["SELECT name, max(revision) as max_rev FROM #{table_name}
               WHERE saved = ? GROUP BY name", 1]
      ), "Load max_revisions for #{self.name}"
    )
    max_revs.map do |row|
      find_by_name_and_revision(row["name"], row["max_rev"].to_i)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Revision.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT id", :conditions => ["saved=1"], :order => 'revision DESC')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and I haven't been able to translate this to active record syntax, but a coworker helped me whip up a nested select that solved this problem for me. Something like this:

```
select id, name, saved, revision
from revisions r
where saved = 1 and
version_no = (select revision 
              from revisions r2
              where saved = 1 and r2.name = r.name
              order by r2.revision desc
              limit 1 
             )
```

Caveat: I'm not sure of the performance implications though, as I suspect this is making a second sub-query for every unique revision field.