# Only show record with highest value with the same attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `teststep` which has the attributes `sequence` and `revision`. The attribute `revision` contains an increased number for every record with the same `sequence`, like this:

```
id: 1, sequence: 1, revision: 1
id: 2, sequence: 2, revision: 1
id: 3, sequence: 2, revision: 2
id: 4, sequence: 2, revision: 3
```

How can I get the records with all different `sequence`'s, but only the highest `revision`, in this case records with `id` 1 and 4? I tried something with distinct, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look over the following post. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222421/with-activerecord-how-can-i-select-records-based-on-the-highest-value-of-a-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222421/with-activerecord-how-can-i-select-records-based-on-the-highest-value-of-a-field)

Answer (score 2):

This code should do the trick

```
TestStep.group(:sequence).pluck(:id, :sequence, 'MAX(revision)')
```

Comment: Thanks, but that returns only 2 attributes, I want the complete records.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Teststep.group(:sequence).having('Max(revision) >= revision')
```

Comment: This: `teststeps.where(teststep_type: "XTestStep").group(:sequence, :id).having('max(revision) >= revision').order(:sequence)` still shows all records, is that because of the extra `where` on `teststep_type`?

Comment: I did researched for your last question, it should work although you combined where, group and having, here is some of more information that probably can help you http://findnerd.com/list/view/Group-By-With-Where-Or-Having-clause-in-Rails/2680/